# Why JPA doesn't respect the foreign key in OneToOne?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, relationship, one-to-one

I have worked with other ORM like Doctrine. Now I'm using JPA with Spring Data.

In a relation OneToOne I know that every row must have a relation with only one row in the other table, Ok! If it is correct who can help me and explain this to me?

Screenshoot from phpmyadmin

**Contacts**

[image: contacts table]

**Employees**
[image: employees table]

This is Contact Object

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contacts")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Employee employee;
    public Contact() {}
    //getters& setters
}
```

And this is the Employee Object

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Contact contact;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Address address;
    private Date created_at;
    private Date updated_at;
    public Employee() {}
    //getters& setters
}
```

Comment: you are getting an exception or something regarding that mapping?

Comment: Have you tried using the `@JoinColumn` annotation? I use it and it works, but I'm not sure if it's required in this scenario.

Comment: Everything looks ok to me. `Contact` is the owning side, so an `employee_id` foreign key gets created in the `contacts` table (and that's exactly what would happen in Doctrine, AFAIK). Could you please explain what was it you expected to happen instead?

Comment: Your statement is NOT true.  A one to one mapping really only specifies that there is a foreign key relationship, and does not require or restrict anything to one and only one reference.  For that, you would need to add a unique constraint on the foreign key.  Your application is responsible for maintaining references, so if you want a strict 1:1, you need to make sure you handle existing contacts before assigning a new or different contact to an employee.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski No and that is why I wrote this quistion.

Comment: @crizzis I thought in one to one relation that an employee must have a only one contact. Look in my contact table there is 2 rows with the same ID of an employee. Is it logic an employee have 2 contact in one to one relation?

Comment: @Chris Is it logic an employee have 2 contact in one to one relation?

Comment: @coladict I think it  is not required I need to know if it is  logic an employee have 2 contact in one to one relation

Comment: Now I see what you meant. If you want to enforce this constraint on the db level, just use `@JoinColumn(unique=true)` on `Contact.employee`

Comment: Yes, it is logical because that is what you did in you object model. You have contact1 referencing emp1, then you change things so that contact2 refences emp1 but you did not fix the contact1 refence first. JPA doesn’t do it for you, and without the above mentioned constraint, there isn’t a problem with the data until the employee is reloaded and two contacts are found. The app need to null or deal with the contact1 employee reference.

Comment: @Chris thank you. I tought that Jpa can even gives an error but now i know 